# Using JavaScript Promise All - is this syntax valid?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have two tables with users, where each id for one user is same in both tables (don't ask why I have two user tables).
At some point, I need to filter users from table 1, and if certain condition is true, I store a promise (deleting request) for each user into (let's call it) tableOnePromises. I do the same for table 2.
In order to empty table 2, I MUST first empty table one due to some requirements.
this is what I did:

```
let tableOnePromises = [];
let tableTwoPromises = [];

tableOne.forEach(item => {
  if(item.deactivated) {
    const tableOneDeleted = supabase
      .from("table-one")
      .delete()
      .match({id: item.id});

    tableOnePromises.push(tableOneDeleted);

    const tableTwoDeleted = supabase
      .from("table-two")
      .delete()
      .match({id: item.id});

    tableOnePromises.push(tableTwoDeleted);
  }
});

await Promise.all(tableOnePromises).then(() => {
  return Promise.all(tableTwoPromises)
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: To find out if the syntax is valid, run the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the code using `await` is inside an `async` function (or at the top level of a module), the *syntax* is correct, but it's probably not what I'd use (in general, avoid mixing `async`/`await` with explicit callbacks via `.then` and `.catch`), and separately it's probably not working quite as you expect (this is borne out by your saying that your code was failing to delete from `table-two`).

For any particular `id` value, your code starts deleting from `table-one` and then **immediately** starts deleting from `table-two` without waiting for the deletion in `table-one` to complete:

```
// STARTS the deletion but doesn't wait for it to finish
const tableOneDeleted = supabase
  .from("table-one")
  .delete()
  .match({id: item.id});
// ...
// Starts deleting from `table-two`, even though the item may still be in `table-one`
const tableTwoDeleted = supabase
  .from("table-two")
  .delete()
  .match({id: item.id});
```

Remember that a promise is just a way of *observing* an asynchronous process; by the time you have the promise, the process it's observing is already underway.¹ So even though you don't wait for the `table-two` promises until later, you start the `table-two` deletions immediately.

> ...I MUST first empty table one due to some requirements...

If by "empty" you mean just that you have to ensure you've done the `delete` for a particular `id` on `table-one` before doing it on `table-two`, you need to wait for the `table-one` deletion to be completed before starting the `table-two` deletion. I'd put that in a function:

```
async function deleteItem(id) {
    await supabase
        .from("table-one")
        .delete()
        .match({id});
    await supabase
        .from("table-two")
        .delete()
        .match({id});
}
```

Then the code becomes:

```
const promises = [];
for (const {deactivated, id} of tableOne) {
    if (deactivated) {
        promises.push(deleteItem(id));
    }
}
await Promise.all(promises); // With the `try`/`catch` if desired
```

...or if it's okay to make two passes through the array:

```
await Promise.all( // With the `try`/`catch` if desired
    tableOne.filter(({deactivated}) => deactivated)
            .map(({id}) => deleteItem(id))
);
```

---

¹ *"...by the time you have the promise, the process it's observing is already underway."* That's the normal case. There is unfortunately a popular document DB library that doesn't start its work on something until/unless you call `then` on the promise for it. But that's an exception, and an anti-pattern.

Comment: @milan.dzeki - Yeah, I just realized why that was. Your code wasn't waiting for the deletion from `table-one` before starting the deletion in `table-two`. If you use the `deleteItem` function above, you don't have that problem, because you wait for the `table-one` deletion for an `id` to be complete before starting the deletion of that `id` from `table-two`.